# Is there a way to pass user defined variable through csv file in JMeter?

Tags: jmeter, jmeter-plugins, beanshell, jmeter-5.0

There are multiple API thread groups and **each thread group will have different configuration** for threads, ramp up time, duration, throughput controller percent execution variable etc.

Can I pass these variable from a .csv file? My aim is to create a config file and pass as a input in non gui mode during execution.

I have seen option for setting property from command line like using J_ or defining property but as number of thread groups are huge I won't be able to use this option. Also CSV data, beanshell preprocessor  config cannot be used as i have to set thread group level details.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [JMeter Plugin Variables From CSV](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/VariablesFromCSV/) to pass the variable from a CSV file to Thread Groups.

1. Create the test data in variable=value format
2. Install the [plugins manager](https://jmeter-plugins.org/install/Install/)
3. Install the Plugin **Variables From CSV** through plugins manager
4. Add **Variables From CSV** config element and configure to read the variables and click on **Test** button 
   [image]
5. Copy the variables
6. Paste into the thread groups

[image]